# How to handle cylinder with flat side?

Tags: modeling, edges

I need to make this object

[image: Cylinder with flat side]

Currently is done by marking creases on some edges, like this:

[image: Mark creases]

First, is there a better way to do this ? I've tried with loop cuts near the edges but it doesn't look as precise as with creases.

The problem is that there's a little issue with the mesh here:

[image]

Is it possible to fix that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe try this topology:

[image]

Result with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Comment: How about this topology? https://i.imgur.com/uPybRZN.png It has the same flow (green), but also some pinching (red): https://i.imgur.com/IR8CagB.png

Comment: Yours seems to be a 32 vertex cylinder, I can't make your solution work properly with a 16 vertex cylinder...

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady... is there a snappy way you've made those little curved green arrows?

Comment: @RobinBetts ShareX https://i.imgur.com/8wNeW3U.gif

Comment: @RobinBetts could be done in geonodes too… https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/293728/60486